# How to identify whether a switch got checked because of a mouse click or some change in the program

Tags: android

I want _swreceiptbarcode to be checked false , when I check _swreceiptqr and vice versa.But How do I distinguish between the human triggered switch and the program triggered switch

```
   _swreceiptbarcode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

               // _swreceiptbarcode.setChecked(true);
                _swreceiptqr.setChecked(false);

        }
    });

    _swreceiptqr.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                _swreceiptbarcode.setChecked(false);
               // _swreceiptqr.setChecked(true);


        }
    });
```

Comment: You know, this can cause endless loop. first onCheckedChanged of switch calls   second which calls first one, first calls then second and so on, am i wrong?

Comment: That s my problem. How do I avoid this

Comment: Do you want this functionality when the user changes the state of a switch or when you change its state by code?

Comment: When the user changes it only , any code wise changes should be ignored

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  _swreceiptbarcode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
               if(isChecked){
               // switch button is checked
               // do something
               }else{
               // switch button is not checked
               // do something
               }
    }
});

_swreceiptqr.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked){
               // switch button is checked
               // do something
            }else{
               // switch button is not checked
               // do something
               }

    }
});
```

Comment: What I want to do ,when one is checked to uncheck the other .But when I do that , on check changed listener takes that in to account and again reset the selection

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the Switch as checked just the once inside `onCreate` you can do that and only set the `OnCheckedChangedListener` afterwards.

Alternatively, you can set the onCheckedChangedListener of your switch to null temporarily while you set its value and then reset it after.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
boolean iCheckedTheBox=false;

barcode.onChangeCheckedListener(){
      if (iCheckedTheBox){
         iCheckedTheBox = false;
         } else {
         iCheckedTheBox = true;
         if (barcode.isChecked())
            receipt.uncheck();
         else
            receipt.check();
         }
}

receipt.onChangeCheckedListener(){
       if (iCheckedTheBox){
         iCheckedTheBox = false;
         } else {
         iCheckedTheBox = true;
         if (receipt.isChecked())
            barcode.uncheck();
         else
            barcode.check();
         }
}
```

Comment: This will only uncheck , it wont check the switches

Comment: Sorry , it doesnt work . Thank you for trying to help

Comment: it is pseudo code.  You have to code it yourself.  That is just the structure

Answer (score 0):

Declare this variable at the class level:

```
private boolean fromCode = false;
```

and these are the listeners:

```
_swreceiptbarcode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (fromCode)
            return;
        fromCode = true;
        _swreceiptqr.setChecked(!isChecked);
        fromCode = false;
    }
});

_swreceiptqr.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (fromCode)
            return;
        fromCode = true;
        _swreceiptbarcode.setChecked(!isChecked);
        fromCode = false;
    }
});
```

Now every time you want to set the state of any of the switches by code, 
you need to do like this:

```
fromCode = true;
_swreceiptbarcode.setChecked(true);
fromCode = false;
```

so it will not trigger the other switch's listener.

Comment: It doesn't check the current switch . It unchecks the other. Checking and unchecking both should be inside oncheckchanged listener

Comment: @Sarah When the user checks the 1st switch the other gets unchecked and vice versa. Isn't this that you want?